# How to show a msgbox after paused/resumed in ahk?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to show a Msgbox when paused and resumed. I am stuck. It does not execute the Msgbox statements. I could understand the reason and modified the code with no luck. Any help for a workaround to show Msgboxes after the state change is really appreciated.

```
!Pause::
If (A_IsPaused)
{               
    MsgBox, , , "Resumed", 1
    Pause
}
Else
{
    MsgBox, , , "Paused", 1     
    Pause
}
```

return

Comment: Your current script is triggered when `Alt`+the [`pause/break`](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pausekey.htm#:~:text=Located%20near%20the%20top%2Dright,while%20the%20user%20steps%20away.) key is pressed, not when the script is paused. Was this intentional?

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I got a solution from @user3419297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're pausing that specific hotkey thread as well.
The other answer works just because the other pause is in another hotkey, usage of `#if` is wrong for this.

You should use the `OperateOnUnderlyingThread`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm#Parameters)</sup> parameter of the `Pause` command like so:

```
!Pause::
    If (A_IsPaused)
    {               
        MsgBox, , , "Resumed", 1
        Pause, , 1
    }
    Else
    {
        MsgBox, , , "Paused", 1     
        Pause, , 1
    }
return
```

Comment: Yes, the OperateOnUnderlyingThread parameter is useful in this scenario!

Answer (score 1):

Because of

> The #If(Win) directive is useful when a particular program ignores a
> key (- combination) or performs some action you find undesirable.

this should work:

```
!Pause::
    MsgBox, , , "Paused", 1 
    Pause
Return


#If (A_IsPaused)

    !Pause::
        MsgBox, , , "Resumed", 1
        Pause
    Return
    
#If
```